# How to choose a language for web map development?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, web-mapping, java, tomcat

I am building a web map application using:

- GeoServer
- OpenLayers
- Tomcat

I would like to build a web application, where the user can log in and **have the map arranged according to their profile**. As I am already using tomcat, I would like to stick with java.

However, I have found that python is more suitable to web programming, so is *jython* an alternative?

This [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16962/how-put-geoserver-layers-behind-authentication) provided some light, but is not complete.

Are there any examples?
`I have thought of using JSF and implementing wms service from geoserver.` Any ideas and suggestions to get started. I am ready to learn new technologies.

Features:

> 1. User Should be able to log in to an application.
> 2. User Should be able to only view maps that their role/user permits.
> 3. The application should only make use of the technology listed above, if possible.

Comment: *I found that python is more suitable to web programming* - I am quite surprised at this line; why do you think this?

Comment: My 2c: use the language(s) you know and avoid adding software to your stack unless it's necessary and/or comes with great advantages.

Comment: @unicoletti I am getting started and using simple js only but it's very error prone and debugging is hard

Comment: I think we'll need a list of features/use cases you want to implement to really suggest a good solution.

Comment: @underdark I have edited the question

Comment: I am unsure this is a GIS question per se; the question is how can I build a secure web site with secure log on and role based map viewing.  Surely this is a security question, not a GI one?  I can't see much value in this question here, but I could have not had enough coffee yet.  I also agree with unicoletti i.e. use what you know.

Comment: @Hairy I want to use technology that is more map related and has more feture that can harvest maps

Comment: @kitex, no I can see that, but your question is more related to web application security, than GI.  I am not having a pop, I just don't think it's *that* related to GIS.  By the looks of it, it's just me, so don't worry.

Answer (score 2):

Even though I've never used it, I think [GeoNode](http://geonode.org/) already does most of what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [GeoScript](http://geoscript.org/) could be the answer to what you want to do (though what you want to do is unclear from the question).

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

> **However, I have found that python is more suitable to web programming**,
>   so is jython an alternative?

That is rather debatable. I suggest you refrain from stating such claims unless you have strong proof. Otherwise it's just an invitation to a flame war.

That said, the language you use will largely be dictated by what you know ( as unicolleti) or by the stack you will use. For example, if you will be using Geoserver then you'll most probably be stuck with Java, at least for server side programming. Though you can code using Python with Jython if you prefer Python's syntax. For this, you can try using [GeoScript](http://geoscript.org/py/quickstart.html#quickstart). It's an attempt to wrap GeoTools in Python. For the client side though, there's no avoiding javascript as most, if not all, web mapping client libraries use it.

For what you want to do though, I agree with unicolleti. GeoNode should cover what you want. It has already  has user management and user access control. You can control permissions at both the [Layer and Map level](http://docs.geonode.org/en/latest/users/index.html).