# Geoserver administration - defining different privileges

Tags: geoserver, security

I need to create separate admin accounts for Geoserver. I'd like to have one superadmin account that would be able to read/edit/delete any style, layergroup, workspace, store or layer - that is what the default admin is already able to.

I also need to have several accounts that would be able to create workspaces, layers and stores, would not be able to edit styles and would be able to edit and delete only the workspaces, layers and stores they created (e.g. if superadmin creates a workspace, he is the only one to delete it).

Is this possible to achieve with Geoserver?

Comment: Please check the tutorials (I assume that you are using version 2.4.x) http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/index.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16962/how-to-put-geoserver-layers-behind-authentication/17074#17074

Comment: I am using version 2.2.5, I don't think version 2.4.x already exists. I've read the linked page earlier, but I didn't quite catch up with the text.

Comment: I think no step by step tutorial is available .You have to do it your self (What you are not understanding in the above tutorials ?) Check out OSGEO link (http://workshops.opengeo.org/geoserver-intro/overview/server.html) .I faced similar problem but at the end of week I was able to configure it properly (thanks to SE.GIS : ) )