# How can users access to special features with geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, security

I want developing an gis application. I want to use [geoserver](http://geoserver.org).  In the application there are some layers(almost 20 layers). And there are some users(more than 100,000 people).

Every people have some features in layers. The people only must access to their own features.

How can I do this with [geoserver](http://geoserver.org)?

Comment: What do you mean by "access"? Read or read-write? Have you looked at geofence? Have you read http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16962/how-to-put-geoserver-layers-behind-authentication?rq=1 ? Also, what is "Avery" in this context.

Comment: yes, 'read' and 'read-write' access. its mean 'every', I wrote 'Avery' mistake.

Comment: You haven't answered the other questions.

Comment: The first time that I see `Geofence`. I read http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16962.  I'm developing a geoserver OWS and then I'm use the geoserver's authentication.

Comment: GeoFence only limit access to **layer** NOT to **features**

Comment: Sorry, I missed that requirement.  I thought you were allocating people to groups, which has some level of access to a layer. I don't think you can do that without some additional code in geoserver.